# get selected Value in listView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have two list in android. One of them is title and the other is ID. I showed the title list in listView. Each title has it's own id. I want to get the id of the each title that I checked.  how can I get the id of each title?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_remark);

 context = getApplicationContext();

    sh = new SchemaHelper(context);

 // -- Display mode of the ListView
 ListView listview= getListView();
 // listview.setChoiceMode(listview.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
 // listview.setChoiceMode(listview.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
 listview.setChoiceMode(listview.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

 //--   text filtering
 listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    final List<String> textList= new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> idList= new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c= sh.getAllRemark();

    for(int i=0; c.moveToNext();i++){
        String caption= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(P_RemarkTable.REM_CAPTION.toString()));
        String id= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(P_RemarkTable.REM_ID.toString()));
        textList.add(caption);
        idList.add(id);


 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, textList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

 listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
     // idList.get(i).toString()
     public void onItemClickListener(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),idList.get(i).toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // barrierID=Integer.parseInt(idList.get(i));
        }

     public void onItemChecked(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idList.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }

     public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){

        // super.onListItemClick(adapterView, view, i, l);

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),idList.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idList.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // barrierID=Integer.parseInt(idList.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });

 }
}

}
```

Non of this method works.
What should I do?

Comment: which value u want to select from listview?

Comment: I wan to select an item from textList and return the id from idList.

Comment: I need the ids from idList

Comment: use  list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Comment: What is the data type of your idList.

Comment: My idList is  String

Comment: Thank you my problem solved.  But now how can i save the ids of the items that the user selected. I need a list of ids that user selected.  how can I save them??